# Translation of the word "informational" and "orientational"

Tags: word-requests

I wonder, how could I express the same meaning for "informational" and "orientational" in Japanese?
I used **有益的【ゆうえきてき】** to mean "informational" and **おおよその/近似の【きんじ】** to mean orientational. But, I am afraid, that I am too far from the right usage, as I use this words mainly for the **gauge=meter**, which is **not calibrated**. So I say:

> Informational/ orientational **gauge**

Also, I would be glad to know, if the offered translation for these two words will be same, in case of changing the context in a next way.

> Orientational/Informational **notes**

Hope I haven't complicated the question too much. Hope to hear your opinion and thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the message. Sorry, but I am not sure, if I undestood you...

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. When you want help figuring out how translate something, you have to include your *try* at finding the Japanese as a rule. So you need to give guesses for "informational" and "orientational"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you might want [目安【めやす】](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%AE%E5%AE%89). This noun implies the value may not be very precise, but it also implies it works fine at least as a rough estimate or a guideline. [See examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%9B%AE%E5%AE%89).

- BMIは必ずしも信頼性は高くないが、肥満度を測る目安としては使える。
  BMI is not necessarily reliable, but usable at least as a rough measure of obesity.
- テレビの視聴率など目安に過ぎない。
  Viewership rating is no more than a rough indicator.

I'm afraid I don't quite get what an "orientational/informational notes" means for now... Could you explain or rephrase it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! 
Yes, of cause. By "orientational/informational notes" i ment helpfull notes, which although cannot be 100% efficient/right in each separate situation. It can be for example some technical vocabulary list with usefull frases, explanations, maybe drawings. But, production area can be do different depending on it’s specialization right? So these notes become just orientational or informative = just for info. 
Sorry, have I managed to explain it plus-minus well..?

Comment: If "Just for your info" is the key connotation here, perhaps you can use [参考情報](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1&ref=sa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the phrase.
Actually, i wish to find some alternative adjective for the word "informational", maybe also "informative", and of cause for "orientational".
But... you know, 参考 sound quite good... As for 2nd context, so for 1st context...